# distances-based dispersion measuring approach

Tags: st.statistics

Is there any known approach or method to measure the dispersion of a set depending on the distances between its points (i.e.: without calculating the average or the mean) ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a finite set $X$, and some system of numbers $d(x,y)$ that can reasonably be interpreted as the distances between the points in $X$.  You can then use $d$ to regard $X$ as a finite metric space.  There is an interesting measure of dispersion for finite metric spaces, called the magnitude.  If I understand correctly, it was largely developed by Tom Leinster and Simon Willerton.  They say that it has useful applications in a number of areas, such as quantifying biodiversity.

You could start by looking at these talks:
http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/barcelona_ig/

Or at this preprint: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.5857v3.pdf